# Matplotlib errorbar changing cap style

Tags: python, matplotlib, errorbar

I am trying to plot errorbars using the matplotlib.errobar function and only have the lower error limits appear. If I use "uplims=True" I get the lower error limits but now with an **arrow** as an error cap. **How do I change that cap back to a horizontal line**?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig = plt.figure()
x = np.arange(10)
y = 2.5 *x 
yerr = np.linspace(0.05, 2, 10)

fig1,ax1=plt.subplots()

#Here error capstyle is a horizontal line
plt.errorbar(x, y + 6, yerr=yerr,capsize=4, label='both limits (default)')

#Error capstyle suddenly changes to arrow
plt.errorbar(x, y + 2, yerr=yerr, uplims=True, label='uplims=True')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured something out.

yerr can be a list of lists:

```
yerr=[lower limits,upper limits]
```

which doesn't change the cap style to an arrow. Then using a list of zeros for the upper limits and a list of error lengths for the lower limits will give error bars on only one side.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this would be to use caplines. This would change the arrows to more normal error bars. If you replaced

```
plt.errorbar(x, y + 2, yerr=yerr, uplims=True, label='uplims=True')
```

with

```
(_, caplines, _,) = plt.errorbar(x, y + 2, yerr=yerr, elinewidth=10, markeredgewidth='10', uplims=True)
caplines[0].set_marker('_')
caplines[0].set_markersize(50)
```

This would create error bars underneath your data. The `elinewidth`, `markeredgewidth` and `set_markersize` are simply to make the error bars look nice, change these values as you see fit. Note that you need to set

```
caplines[0].set_marker('_')
caplines[0].set_markersize(50)
```

after every `plt.errorbar`, you cannot set these only once with this setup.